# Condition checking in python with user input

Tags: python

I tried taking an input from keyboard. the checking that input with an if else statement. But everytime the else part is working. The if statement does not happen to be true. I can't understand where I am going wrong.

Here is what I have done.

```
abc= raw_input("Enter a  2 digit number");
if abc==6:
    print "Its party time!!!"
else:
    print "Its work time"
```

Please suggest

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your input variable is a string. You need to cast it to an integer to correctly compare it to 6.

`if int(abc) == 6:`

Answer (score 0):

`raw_input` returns a string. `abc` is a string, and a string will never be equal with an integer. Try casting `abc` or the return value of `raw_input()`. Or, you can make `6` a string.

**Casting the return value of** `raw_input()` **:**

```
abc = int( raw_input('Enter a 2 digit number') )
```

**Casting** `abc` **:**

`abc = int(abc)`

or

`if int(abc) == 6:`

**Changing** `6` **to string :**

```
if abc == '6':
```

Answer (score -1):

```
>>> abc= raw_input("Enter a  2 digit number")
Enter a  2 digit number6
>>> if int(abc) == 6:
    print "Its party time!!!"


Its party time!!!
>>>
```