# i am not able to calculate my answer and always gives answer err

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def add(x, y): 
   return x + y

def sub(x, y):
    return x - y

def multiply(x, y ):
    return x * y

def div(x, y):
    return x / y

print("Select Operation:")

print("1.add")

print("2.sub")

print("3.multiply")

print("4.div")

choice = input("enter your operation number: ")

a = int(input("enter the first number:"))

b = int(input("enter the second number: "))

if choice == 1:
    print(a,"+",b,"=", add(a,b))
elif choice == 2:    
    print(a,"-",b,"=", sub(a,b))
elif choice == 3:  
    print(a,"*",b,"=", multiply(a,b))
elif choice == 4:   
    print(a,"/",b,"=", div(a,b))
else:   
    print("err")
```

Comment: Hello, this is a bit tough to read.  You should have indentation in your code, it would be very helpful to see that here.  What you can do is copy/paste your code, highlight it all and hit the { } button to get it legible.  Also you should explain what you expect your program to do and what the error is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Condition checking in python with user input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31368624/condition-checking-in-python-with-user-input)

Answer (score 1):

Pay attention, when inputing something, it's a **string**.

So, when doing: `choice == 1`, it tries to do: `'1' == 1`, which is false

Do:

```
 if choice == '1':
    print(a,"+",b,"=", add(a,b))
 elif choice == '2':
    print(a,"-",b,"=", sub(a,b))
 elif choice == '3':
    print(a,"*",b,"=", multiply(a,b))
 elif choice == '4':
    # complete..
```

Comment: `choice = int(input("enter your operation number: "))` is a little easier in my opinion, but you are right.